# RabbitMQ/Pika blocking consumer with evenlet

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika, eventlet

I am working on a larger application that requires eventlet, and now requires rabbitMQ as well. It appears that eventlet is causing the pika consumer thread to block execution of additional workers. I know Pika is not considered thread-safe, so I have everything, including the connection, within it's own thread. I would assume the blocking connection should only block the consumer thread. How can I get pika and eventlet to work together? In the below example, the workers thread never prints anything out, but commenting out `eventlet.monkey_patch()` allows both threads to execute.

```
import threading
import pika

import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print body
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)


def consumer():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='test', durable=True,
                          exclusive=False, auto_delete=False)
    channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='test')
    channel.start_consuming()


def start_consumer_thread():
    # initialize a listener thread
    consumer_thread = threading.Thread(target=consumer)
    consumer_thread.start()

def worker():
    start_consumer_thread()
    for x in range(1,10000):
        print x


x = threading.Thread(target=worker())
x.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pika and `eventlet.monkey_patch` are not compatible. You will have to use `eventlet` without patching system calls, if that is possible.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to periodically check for a message in queue and consume it rather than have an never ending blocking loop?

Comment: Not sure if that is true. oslo.messaging is using pika, and it's monkey patching afaik. You should always monkey patch before importing other libraries. Try to move monkey_patch before the pika import.

Comment: @eandersson - that doesn't appear to be the case anymore [link](https://github.com/openstack/oslo.messaging/blob/40532a2a457eba1179183654079e0ed81ddbcc48/releasenotes/notes/pika-driver-has-been-deprecated-e2407fa53c91fe5c.yaml). This is a shame since Pika is much more reliable than kombu or other python libraries for RabbitMQ.

Comment: Yea - it was a misstep that when they introduced pika support, they didn't allow for a mix between the pika and kombu drivers. So if you wanted to use pika, you had to take down your whole cloud to update the configuration.

Comment: btw for reliability! I prefer my amqp library =]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a `pika` consumer working with `eventlet` by monkey patching as early as possible, and also importing `pika` in a patched manner.

Import and patch stdlib first:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

Then import and patch `pika` itself:

```
pika = eventlet.import_patched('pika')
```

I used this import strategy in conjunction with the asynchronous_consumer_example: https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html and used `eventlet` primitives rather than `threading` to achieve a non-blocking consumer.